# Angular $scope values not recognized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just trying to figure out why this basic setup isn't working. I've got it to run before, but for some reason when I open up the page, the {{expression}} is recognized but the values within the controller are not. The page just displays blank instead of saying "Testing" as it should.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='bookerApp'>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
<script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/controllers/BookerController.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-contoller='BookerController'>
{{test}}
<div class='booker-head'>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('bookerApp', []);

app.controller('BookerController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    $scope.test = "Testing";

}]);
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you check what message you see in your console?

Comment: @Przemek I'm getting no errors in my console at all, the expression value just appears to be blank for some reason.

Comment: Your styles might be making it same color as the background. CTRL+A to do a select all and see if you see the text

Comment: @fahadash Unfortunately that's not it. Any other text I put beside the {{test}} expression appears black again a white background, and the CTRL+A reveals no text at all without changing the html for the testing text.

Comment: please try to add this on the end of your code: setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('html'), ['bookerApp']);
});

Comment: @Przemek I tried doing as you suggested but it's still not working. I tried with it placed within the controller code and outside but either way resulted in no change.

Comment: Testing in IE? have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Also try without your style.css, there can be a lot of other things that can be done to text to make it invisible

Comment: @fahadash still the same result without any styles, and I've been testing in Chrome. IE just shows the {{expression}} in the brackets.

Comment: your html says `<body ng-contoller='BookerController'>`. Notice the missing r in cont**r**oller

Comment: @Pevara I would kill to get eyeballs that you have :)

Comment: Those are the most horrible bugs to find ;-) And trust me, I only see them in someone elses code...

Comment: @Pevara I'm both extremely embarrassed and impressed. Thank you so much!

Comment: yw, we've all been there ;) I'll actually go ahead and vote for the closure of this question, not much use in keeping your typo here for future visitors

Comment: @Pevara I'm still new to the community so I was wondering if I should delete the post in this case?

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine as well I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('bookerApp', []);


  app.controller('BookerController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
      $scope.test = "Testing: its working";

    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="bookerApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BookerController">
  <h1>Angular Setup</h1>
  <p>{{test}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If paths were wrong would see `{{test}}` in the page...not a blank

Comment: That's what I believed too. I tried testing it with all the js files in the same folder as the html and pointing to them resulted in a blank page still.

Comment: Agreed. Will edit my response. Did you try my snippet?

Comment: When I use this code it actually works once I refer to the location "js/controllers/BookerController.js". Any idea why my code doesn't work but yours does?

Comment: I tried to replicate your error but wasn't successful, the code I have works. see https://github.com/felixgondwe/BlankAngularIssue/tree/develop/Test and check against your code if its matching what you're looking for. nvm, i see you have it resolved, that 'r' you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('bookerApp', []);

  myApp.controller('BookerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    $scope.test = "Testing";

  }]);
})(window.angular);




<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="bookerApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>bookerApp</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>

  <body ng-contoller='BookerController'>
    {{test}}
  </body>
  <script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/controllers/BookerController.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted as you posted but still no result for some reason.